# how to properly echo onclick='function($var)'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, echo, quotes

When I echo this table :

```
echo "<table class='aTable'  border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellido</th>
<th>Telefono</th>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Ver Orden</th>
</tr>";

while($row = $gsent->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['IdOrder'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Apellido'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Phone'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['TimeStamp'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' name='ID' value='VER' onclick='showOrder({$row['IdOrder']})'>"."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I want the last column to show a button which triggers a Javascript function

```
    <script>
        function showOrder(IdOrder){
            jQuery('#list-data').val(IdOrder);
            document.getElementById("formOrder").submit();
            console.log('PHP:  ' + IdOrder );

            var delayMillis = 500;
            setTimeout(function() {
              window.location.href = 'ask.php';
               }, delayMillis);
}
</script>
```

Everything works fine when the button `$row['IdOrder']` contains a number, eg 1521 or 00254 but when it has a hexadecimal number it wont work or behaves in a strange way eg on ADAC in
chrome console this error shows up:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ADAC is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Or if the Hex is 39E3 the function runs but I get this number in the function 39000 which I dont know why but is correct because in google if I put 39E3 to decimal I get that number but I dont want the 39E3 to convert itself to 39000 so my guess is that the variable $row['IdOrder'] is beeing Treated different if its start with a number or with a letter, I want `$row['IdOrder']`  always be treated like a text to avoid this weird conversions if its possible or maybe, do 
I have to take another path?

Comment: Try with `{$row["IdOrder"]}`.

Comment: pass `$row['IdOrder']` as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `IdOrder` is not a number-only value, you have to wrap it  with quotes, to become a string:

```
"<input type='submit' name='ID' value='VER' onclick='showOrder(\"{$row['IdOrder']}\")'>"
```

It should print something like:

```
<input type='submit' name='ID' value='VER' onclick='showOrder("myId")'>
```

So the compiler won't try to guess that `ADAC` is an object instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
{$row['IdOrder']}
```

with

```
\"{$row['IdOrder']}\"
```

to make it a string.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown huh? Our comments, this answer and yours are all the same? How are they wrong solutions?

Comment: I wonder why votes are anonymous. The data is stored obviously, if a user leaves,you lose or gain points gained or lost from their votes.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice the other was incorrect :|